# Django - strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-errors

In my application user is entering his name, email, meeting date and meeting hour and I want to save all these information to my database. But application is not running. I'm getting `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not None` but don't what is the reason. Everything seems like true.

`models.py`:

```
def index(request):
    context = {
        'schedules': Schedule.objects.all()
    }

    participant_name = request.POST.get('name')
    participant_email = request.POST.get('email')
    meeting_date = request.POST.get('date')
    meeting_hour = request.POST.get('hour')
    converted_meeting_date = datetime.strptime(request.POST.get('date'), "%m-%d-%Y")
    converted_meeting_hour = datetime.strptime(request.POST.get('hour'), "%H:%M")
    if request.POST.get('participant_email'):
        Schedule.objects.create(
            participant_name = request.POST.get('name'),
            participant_email = request.POST.get('email'),
            meeting_date = converted_meeting_date,
            meeting_hour = converted_meeting_hour
        )
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

`models.py`:

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    participant_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    participant_email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    meeting_date = models.DateField()
    meeting_hour = models.TimeField()
    is_scheduled = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.participant_name
```

Comment: check if any of `request.POST.get('date')` or `request.POST.get('hour')` are None

Comment: @AvielNiego, man, hello, have a good day. Can you check please my this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61156491/django-form-save-is-not-creating-modelform ? Last days my question reach very few people, and can't tag someone. Please, help me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if both meeting_date and meeting_hour are not None and also you need to convert them into string before applying strptime to them.

```
def index(request):
    context = {
        'schedules': Schedule.objects.all()
    }

    participant_name = request.POST.get('name')
    participant_email = request.POST.get('email')
    meeting_date = str(request.POST.get('date'))
    meeting_hour = str(request.POST.get('hour'))
    converted_meeting_date = datetime.strptime(request.POST.get('date'), "%m-%d-%Y").date() if meeting_date else None
    converted_meeting_hour = datetime.strptime(request.POST.get('hour'), "%H:%M").time() if meeting_hour else None
    if request.POST.get('participant_email'):
        Schedule.objects.create(
            participant_name = request.POST.get('name'),
            participant_email = request.POST.get('email'),
            meeting_date = converted_meeting_date,
            meeting_hour = converted_meeting_hour
        )
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: Man, now it works, but model is not writing to database. What can be reason ?

Comment: what is the datatype of those columns in schedule ?

Comment: I've added ```models.py``` codes, brother, or you mean something different ?

Comment: Just try to check the type of both the fields before they are added into your Model. If they are the same as your columns, it shouldnt be an issue

Comment: Please, brother, help me, I can't check :(

Comment: I've deleted everything related with date and leave only username and email fields, but schedule object is not creating again